# Problema em mostrar o resultado no php quando há apenas um registro no BD

Tags: php, mysql

O código abaixo retorna algum valor, quando há diversos registros com mesmo nome ou parecido, quando há somente um registro no bd não retorna o valor desse registro.

```
<?php
include_once '../../Modulos/Database/Banco.php';

$pesquisa=$_POST['pesquisa'];
echo ($pesquisa);
$sql = "select * from fornecedor where razaoSocial like '%$pesquisa%' or nomeFantasia like '%$pesquisa%';";
$salva = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

if ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($salva)) {
   while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($salva)) {

       $id = $resultado[0];
       $razaoSocial = $resultado[1];
       $cnpj = $resultado[2];
       $nomeFantasia = $resultado[3];
       $tel = $resultado[4];
       $contato = $resultado[5];
       $email = $resultado[6];
       //$dataCadastro = $resultado[6]
       // testando a função edita.php
       //começará com 0 e vai evoluindo, isso também pode registrar quantas resultados tem a tabela
       $parimpar++;
       //A tabela do sbadmin precisa marcar com par ou ímpar cada linha
       if ($id % 2 == 0) {
           $parimpar = "odd";
       } else {
           $parimpar = "even";
       }

       //echo"<tr><th>$id</th><th>$nome</th><th>$codBarra</th><th>$descricao</th><th>$vCusto</th><th>$vVenda</th></tr>";

       echo'

       <tr class="' . $parimpar . ' gradeX">
       <td><a href="cadastrarPedido.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $id . '</a></td>
       <td>' . $razaoSocial . '</td>
       <td>' . $cnpj . '</td>
       <td>' . $nomeFantasia . '</td>
       <td class="center">' . $tel . '</td>
       <td class="center">' . $contato . '</td>
       <td>' . $email . '</td>
       </tr>';


       }
   } else {
       echo ("Problema ao realizar a consulta n banco de dados" . mysqli_error($conexao));
   }

   mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Comment: Nesse caso particular que está a dizer que não retorna o valor a variável `$sql` tem que valor ? Pode consultar com `var_dump($sql);`

Comment: string(87) "select * from fornecedor where razaoSocial like '%novo%' or nomeFantasia like '%novo%';"

Comment: Tem algum registo com `razaoSocial` ou `nomeFantasia` com `novo` ? Quando executa essa consulta no *phpMyAdmin* obtem algum resultado?

Comment: Sim, tenho apenas um registro com nomeFantasia novo e no phpmysadmin funciona corretamente. Nesse tabela tenho vários nomeFantasia teste e código está funcionando quando a pesquisa é teste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `if` está a ler a primeira linha da tabela resultante e logo a seguir quando vai entrar no `while` lê a segunda linha sem utilizar a primeira:

```
if ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($salva)) { //lê a primeira
   while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($salva)) { //aqui lê a segunda
```

Acaba assim por perder o primeiro registo.

Pode corrigir trocando o seu `if` para testar a quantidade de registos que tem disponiveis:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($salva) > 0){
   while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($salva)) {
```